# How to retrieve another user's info like email and displayName in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a `users` node in Firebase storing each user's information, **but excluding** `displayName and`email`, which is in firebase auth DB.

One day, I realise that I also need user's `displayName` and `email` info. 
For example, in a page created by another user, I want to display that user's displayName and email.

By given that

1. `displayName` and `email` are not stored under the `users` node,
2. the user's uniqueId is known

Is it possible to retrieve the user's `displayName` and `email` from firebase auth DB (by either normal user or admin)?
or what shall I do for users that were already created in firebase?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the AdminSDK it is possible like explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).

In the doc there is examples for every method, but in your case I guess that you searched for this

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
    .then(function(userRecord) {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
    });
```

You can do things like `userRecord.displayName`. The full interface is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord).

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
So I understand that any other users' data, which needs to be retrieved by clients, should be saved in the `users` node regardless the auth DB has it or not. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Therefor you have the user ceation trigger in Cloudfunctions for Firebase