# How to know other users displayName and photo url using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a review site.
I'm attempting to show a poster's displayName and photo, which means whatever people login in or not, any guys can see the poster's displayName and photo. The poster first log in and then post a review. other guys can see the post content, the poster's displayName, and photo url. How can you achieve it with Firebase Auth and Firestore?

I know that I can do it by using getUser or getUsers function from this ticket.
[How to retrieve another user's info like email and displayName in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786735/how-to-retrieve-another-users-info-like-email-and-displayname-in-firebase)

However, those functions seems to be for admin so it's not good to use it in the above case due to security issue.

Any advice?

Comment: So if some user Post something he won't assign to his post, his displayName and photo?

Comment: If he doesn't do it, how does your server know it is his post?

Comment: No, the poster must login first. Then the guy can post. Non-logged-in users can see the post content, the poster's displayName, and url

Comment: So if user have a display name and photo. And he post a Post he will assign his display name and photo to this post so everyone knows who wrote the post?

Comment: Can I retrieve the poster's displayName and photo url by uid using Firebase Admin SDK from client side? I store only the poster's uid of Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Poster well know who is he without Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: So stop only storing poster uid!

Comment: I want to show the poster's displayName and photo url when OTHER guys see the review site and the post in a browser.

Comment: "So stop only storing poster uid! " => But, what if the poster change his displayName or photo url?

Comment: You can trigger a function which will find his posts and override data.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase admin SDK is only to use on server side. If you want to have a poster display name and photo, just add it to a post he creates or create a collection with a poster's information in it. So when you get a post with owner `uid` you can again fetch data with poster information.

I recommend having first option because it needs just one read for users to make. And like I said in comment if user change some think you can find all his posts and change his display name or photo there. Feel less reliable, but in reality you don't want to have 50k reads instead of 25k out of poster 5 posts.